# Getting a 500 Error on admin-ajax.php during fopen function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am building a fairly large Wordpress Multisite. One of the key bits of functionality is a product importer.

What I am doing, is uploading a CSV into the media library, then running a fopen function on that file. You can "trigger" this by hitting a button which using ajax then runs the import function.

With the information it gets, it then runs a foreach function, using wp_insert_post one by one.

Now when I built this originally, it was fine on my local server. It would insert 300 products with no issues.

On the remote server, it crashes after around 30 seconds. We've increased the max execution time, as well as upload limits and still no joy.

The issue is now affecting my local development too. This is the error I am getting:

> "load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.5.3:4
>   POST http://dev-url.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)"

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: General rule: if you get a 500, the FIRST place you go to check is the server error logs. Until you know what caused the 500, anything else you do is just randomly poking around in the dark.

Comment: What is the 500 sever error you are getting? can you see the error in your logs?

Comment: @MarcB, I 100% agree with that. OP, please listen to Marc's advice and please edit your question to include your server logs. Additionally, please include some of the PHP code where the error is occurring, as this might be an issue with your code itself. You might consider looking into increasing the memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');`. That is a *"poking around in the dark"* suggestion, but given how many products you have, that might be one of the issues. Also, the 30 second run time seems high, in my opinion. Is that expected, and does the local server take that long?